# TypeORM not creating expected foreign keys

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm setting up TypeORM with a MySQL DB - here are 2 tables that should surely introduce foreign keys:

```
@Entity('Area')
export class Area {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  Id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  Name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  CreatedAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  UpdatedAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Subarea, (Subarea) => Subarea.Area)
  Subareas: Subarea[];
}
```

and

```
@Entity('Subarea')
export class Subarea {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  Id: string;

  @Column()
  Name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  CreatedAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  UpdatedAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => Area, (Area) => Area.Subareas) 
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'AreaId', referencedColumnName: 'Id' })
  Area: Area;
}
```

Yet I get 2 totally separate, unrelated tables?

Answer (score 0):

One of the devs helped me confirm it is a bug in current release, but has been fixed in master: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/8038